# Combining a while loop with Task.Run() in C#

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, async-await

I'm pretty new to multithread applications in C# and I'm trying to edit my code below so that it runs on multiple threads. Right now it operates synchronously and it takes up very little cpu power. I need it to run much faster on multiple threads. My thought was starting a task for each core and then when a task finishes, allow another to take its place or something like that if it is possible.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string connectionString = CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("Microsoft.ServiceBus.ConnectionString");
        QueueClient Client = QueueClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString, "OoplesQueue");

        try
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Task.Run(() => processCalculations(Client));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
        }
    }

    public static ConnectionMultiplexer connection;
    public static IDatabase cache;

    public static async Task processCalculations(QueueClient client)
    {
        try
        {
            BrokeredMessage message = await client.ReceiveAsync();

            if (message != null)
            {
                if (connection == null || !connection.IsConnected)
                {

                    connection = await ConnectionMultiplexer.ConnectAsync("connection,SyncTimeout=10000,ConnectTimeout=10000");
                    //connection = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("connection,SyncTimeout=10000,ConnectTimeout=10000");
                }

                cache = connection.GetDatabase();

                string sandpKey = message.Properties["sandp"].ToString();
                string dateKey = message.Properties["date"].ToString();
                string symbolclassKey = message.Properties["symbolclass"].ToString();
                string stockdataKey = message.Properties["stockdata"].ToString();
                string stockcomparedataKey = message.Properties["stockcomparedata"].ToString();

                List<StockData> sandp = cache.Get<List<StockData>>(sandpKey);
                DateTime date = cache.Get<DateTime>(dateKey);
                SymbolInfo symbolinfo = cache.Get<SymbolInfo>(symbolclassKey);
                List<StockData> stockdata = cache.Get<List<StockData>>(stockdataKey);
                List<StockMarketCompare> stockcomparedata = cache.Get<List<StockMarketCompare>>(stockcomparedataKey);

                StockRating rating = performCalculations(symbolinfo, date, sandp, stockdata, stockcomparedata);

                if (rating != null)
                {
                    saveToTable(rating);
                    if (message.LockedUntilUtc.Minute <= 1)
                    {
                        await message.RenewLockAsync();
                    }
                    await message.CompleteAsync();
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Message " + message.MessageId + " Completed!");
                    await message.CompleteAsync();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (TimeoutException time)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(time.Message);
        }
        catch (MessageLockLostException locks)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(locks.Message);
        }
        catch (RedisConnectionException redis)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Start the redis server service!");
        }
        catch (MessagingCommunicationException communication)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(communication.Message);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You simply need a Parallel.ForEach. The async IO here gains you nothing because you will only have as many threads as there are CPU cores.

Comment: The only chance to make it "faster" is to identify _things_ which run sequentiell now and can run in parallel. I can't see such a thing from your code.

Comment: Does your queue keep filling as you process each client?

Comment: @usr I can't use a parallel.foreach loop because my program has to wait for it to be assigned a task from the queue

Comment: Who do I mark as the answer since all 3 answers helped me out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like a classic producer-consumer pattern.

In this case, where you need concurrency combined with **async IO** bound operations (such as retrieving data from a Redis cache) and **CPU bound** operations (such as doing compute bound calculations), i'd leverage [TPL Dataflow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603(v=vs.110).aspx) for the job.

You can use a `ActionBlock<T>` which is responsible for processing of a single action you pass to it. Behind the scenes, it takes care of concurrency, while you can limit it as you want by passing it an `ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions`.

You start off by creating the `ActionBlock<BrokeredMessage>`:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var actionBlock = new ActionBlock<BrokeredMessage>(async message =>
                      await ProcessCalculationsAsync(message),
                      new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions 
                      {
                          MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount
                      });

    var produceMessagesTask = Task.Run(async () => await
                                                   ProduceBrokeredMessagesAsync(client, 
                                                   actionBlock));

    produceMessagesTask.Wait();
}
```

Now lets look what `ProduceBrokeredMessageAsync`. It simply receives your `QueueClient` and the `ActionBlock` to the the following:

```
private async Task ProduceBrokeredMessagesAsync(QueueClient client,
                                                ActionBlock<BrokeredMessage> actionBlock)
{
    BrokeredMessage message;
    while ((message = await client.ReceiveAsync()) != null)
    {
        await actionBlock.SendAsync(message);
    }
    actionBlock.Complete();
    await actionBlock.Completion;
}
```

What this does is while you receive messages from your `QueueClient`, it will asynchronously post the message to the `ActionBlock`, which will process those message concurrently.

Comment: Sorry for sounding dumb but what do you mean by processing the message concurrently?

Comment: @user3610374 No sounding dumb at all. What you actually want is to process brokered messages as they come, right? This way, while the `QueueClient` keeps producing messages, you can process them *simultaneously* instead of sequentially.

Comment: Also with using my code above, I'm not understanding your line where it says await action.SendAsync(message); am I supposed to replace that with the call for the processCalculations method?

Comment: @user3610374 No, because the `ActionBlock` encapsulates your `processCalculations` method. It posts asynchronously to it, and the `ActionBlock` takes care of the concurrent execution of the method.

Comment: I put in your code and I'm getting this exception:  Error 1 An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'QueueProcessor.Program.ProduceBrokeredMessagesAsync(Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.QueueClient, System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow.ActionBlock<Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.BrokeredMessage>)'
            QueueClient client = QueueClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString, "OoplesQueue");

Comment: Nevermind. I didn't notice that the method I copied and pasted from you wasn't marked as static

Comment: @user3610374 I suggest you read into TPL Dataflow a bit to understand the execution flow. It is quite elegant.

Comment: Is this a pretty new concept for .net because I'm only just now hearing about it. I'm guessing it came with .net 4.5?

Comment: It came out together with the TPL (Task Parallel Library) changes with .NET 4.5. It is *pretty* new and doesn't come bundled into the BCL. Its distributed through [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Tpl.Dataflow/4.5.24).

Answer (score 3):

> Right now it operates synchronously and it takes up very little cpu power. I need it to run much faster on multiple threads.

"Multiple threads" doesn't necessarily mean "faster". That is only true if you have multiple calculations to perform that are independent of each other, and they are CPU-bound (meaning they mainly involve CPU operations, not IO operations).

Additionally, async doesn't necessarily mean multiple threads. It just means your operation is not blocking a process thread while in progress. If you're starting another thread and blocking it, then that *looks like* async but it really isn't. Check out this Channel 9 video: [Async Library Methods Shouldn't Lie](http://search.channel9.msdn.com/content/result?sid=a557f152-5a66-4f4c-ba41-15fe546512d3&rid=5f72dc9e-70e0-40b8-bac6-a2b50165a23a)

Most of your operations in `processCalculations` look like they are dependent on each other; however, this part might be a potential improvement point:

```
List<StockData> sandp = cache.Get<List<StockData>>(sandpKey);
DateTime date = cache.Get<DateTime>(dateKey);
SymbolInfo symbolinfo = cache.Get<SymbolInfo>(symbolclassKey);
List<StockData> stockdata = cache.Get<List<StockData>>(stockdataKey);
List<StockMarketCompare> stockcomparedata = cache.Get<List<StockMarketCompare>>(stockcomparedataKey);
StockRating rating = performCalculations(symbolinfo, date, sandp, stockdata, stockcomparedata);
```

I'm not familiar with the API you're using but IF it includes an async equivalent of the `Get` method you might be able to do those IO operations asynchronously in parallel, e.g.:

```
var sandpTask = List<StockData> sandp = cache.GetAsync<List<StockData>>(sandpKey);
var dateTask = cache.GetAsync<DateTime>(dateKey);
var symbolinfoTask = cache.GetAsync<SymbolInfo>(symbolclassKey);
var stockdataTask = cache.GetAsync<List<StockData>>(stockdataKey);
var stockcomparedataTask = cache.GetAsync<List<StockMarketCompare>>(stockcomparedataKey);

await Task.WhenAll(sandpTask, dateTask,symbolinfoTask,
    stockdataTask, stockcomparedataTask);

List<StockData> sandp = sandpTask.Result;
DateTime date = dateTask.Result;
SymbolInfo symbolinfo = symbolinfoTask.Result;
List<StockData> stockdata = stockdataTask.Result;
List<StockMarketCompare> stockcomparedata = stockcomparedataTask.Result;

StockRating rating = performCalculations(symbolinfo, date, sandp, stockdata, stockcomparedata);
```

Also, note that you don't need to wrap the processCalculations call in another Task since it already returns a task:

```
// instead of Task.Run(() => processCalculations(message));
processCalculations(message);
```

Comment: I edited my code to show the changes you suggest. Does all of it look correct?

Comment: @user3610374 you should keep the original question for reference. Now others can't understand the question and answers, since they can't see the original code.

Comment: I'm trying to get it back to the original right now

Comment: and yes, you applied the points I made correctly. However, I don't know if a method like `GetAsync` exists. That's kind of why I put a big IF in the answer. You'll need to look up the documentation.

Comment: It does and that is why I changed it to use that instead

Comment: My last question for your edit is should I call await processCalculations(message) or processCalculations(message)?

Comment: You can't put `await` there because that would require Main to be async, which you can't do. But you can move it to another async method and use `await`. Just note that if you put awai, it will basically pause the while loop until processCalculations is completed on each iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

You need two parts:

Part 1 waits for an incoming message: `ConnectAsync()` this runs in a simple loop. Whenever something is received an instance of Part2 is started to process the incoming message.

Part2 runs in another thread / in the background and processes a single incoming message.

That way several instances of `Part2` may run in parallel.

So your structure is like this:

```
while (true)
{
    connection = await ConnectionMultiplexer.ConnectAsync(...);
    StartProcessCalculationsInBackground(connection, ...); // return immediately
}
```

Comment: I edited my code to show the changes I made using your idea. Is my code now matching what you are suggesting?

Comment: You should not edit your question, making other comments and answers obsolet (look silly)

Comment: Oh I'm sorry about that. I edited it but in the future I will add on any updates

Comment: Since the method for part 2 returns a task because it is an async method, do I need to call it like this: BrokeredMessage message = await client.ReceiveAsync();
                await processCalculations(message);

or like this:

BrokeredMessage message = await client.ReceiveAsync();
                processCalculations(message);

Comment: Both: No! do not `await Part2` start it in the background (see other answers)